# How to fetch data if we have multiple model files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route file **user.js** and 2 model files, **hmscategory.js** and **todo.js**. I am getting data from db when I hit http://localhost:5000/user/todo, but am not getting any data when I hit http://localhost:5000/user/hmscategory.

---

**user.js**

```
const Category = require('../models/hmscategory');
const Todo = require('../models/todo');

var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/hmscategory', (req, res, next) => {
    Category.find({})
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(next)
});

router.get('/todo', (req, res, next) => {
    // this will return all the data, 
    // exposing only the id and action field to the client
    Todo.find({})
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(next)
});

module.exports = router;
```

**todo.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//create schema for todo
const TodoSchema = new Schema({
    action: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'The todo text field is required']
    }
})

//create model for todo
const Todo = mongoose.model('todos', TodoSchema);

module.exports = Todo;
```

**hmscategory.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//create schema for todo
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    category_name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'The todo text field is required']
    }
})

//create model for todo
const Category = mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

Comment: I am new in node, can anyone me help me on it

Comment: is data present in mongodb for category ?

Comment: yes data is present

Comment: You receive an empty array of data in response to /hmscategory request ?

Comment: What are you getting as the response when you do a GET request to `/user/hmscategory`?

Comment: I am getting empty array

Comment: It seem fine. Check again your table name `category` -  `categories` or `categorys`, and you database name.